# Azure DevOps pipeline fails on Wordpress repo with Docker

Tags: wordpress, docker, azure-pipelines

we're currently migrating our repo's from github to azure devops including the build streets.
in one of the repos we have a wordpress website combined with docker. But sadly our azure pipeline fails.

We get the error :

```
##[error]Unhandled: Failed find: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/vsts/work/1/s/wp-content/db.php'
```

(offcourse, the file is there in the repo, path and name checked)

This is our docker file (yes only 1 line):

```
FROM quay.io/presslabs/wordpress-runtime:5.5.1-php-7.4
```

Our docker compose file

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
       - memcached
     build: .
     volumes:
       - ./config:/app/config
       - ./wp-content:/app/web/wp-content
     ports:
       - "8080:8080"
     restart: always
     environment:
       DB_HOST: db:3306
       DB_USER: xxxxxx
       DB_PASSWORD: xxxxx
       DB_NAME: xxxxx
       MEMCACHED_HOST: memcached:11211
       WP_HOME: http://localhost:8080
       WP_SITEURL: http://localhost:8080/wp
       WP_ENV: development

   db:
     image: percona:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxxxxxx
       MYSQL_DATABASE: xxxxx
       MYSQL_USER: xxxxxx
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: xxxxxxxxxxxxx

   memcached:
     image: memcached:1.5

volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

and our azurepipelines file

```
trigger:
- master

variables:
  DockerImageName: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  
steps:
- task: CmdLine@1
  displayName: 'Lock image version in deployment.yaml'
  inputs:
    filename: /bin/bash
    arguments: '-c "awk ''{gsub(\"xxxxxxxxxx\", \"gcr.io/$(DockerImageName):$(Build.BuildId)\", $0); print}'' deployment.yaml > $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/deployment.yaml"'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: 'gcr-publisher'
    command: 'buildAndPush'
    Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
```

What do we do wrong?
Our local docker works with the command:

```
docker build -t 'test' .
```

Comment: try to add `workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'` in the Docker task, or `buildContext: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'`

Comment: both options didn't work

Comment: You need to copy the files into your docker image, you are just using the image but are not copying the files from your solutions into it.